# How to paste a register inside of the expression register

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

If I am using evil-mode and insert mode, is it possible to paste another register once I have entered `C-r =`?

When I try this, instead of inserting the register I requested e.g. `C-r "`, which should insert the last thing I deleted, it tries to do a backward search.

I am trying to use the following workflow:

- command - comment
- `/^[0-9][0-9]/` - find a two digit number at the start of line
- `de` - delete the number
- `i` - go into insert mode
- `C-r =` - invoke the expression register
- `(- 2018 C-r "` - subtract original number from 2018

So, in essence, I want to replace a number at the start of line by the its value subtracted from `2018`.

Comment: The sexp in your last bullet would be invalid. `Ctrl-R` would be interpreted as a variable to be evaluated, and `")` would be interpreted as the start of a string. You apparently want to subtract the *value returned by* the register you assigned.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for correcting my incorrect key mapping (I used the same values as in other questions but obviously the chord is control and r not control and R). However C-r " in the expression register mini buffer does not appear to be replaced by the value held in the " register.